# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' when starting a process with UseShellExecute = False

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

When I start a console app from an asp.net application and set UseShellExecute = False, I get the error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800703F0)

But when I start it with UseShellExecute = True, it works. Both the asp.net and the console app are using .net 4.6.1. The EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll are in the same folder as the console app.

I have tried everything and so far cannot get rid of the error. I prefer to UseShellExecute = False so that I can redirect the output to the asp.net app. It appears that it cannot find the dlls but it should since it is the same folder.

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
     Dim filename As String = "C:\apps\test.exe"
        Dim filepath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)


        Dim proc = New Process() With {
        .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo() With {
        .FileName = filename,
        .WorkingDirectory = filepath,
        .UseShellExecute = False,
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True,
        .RedirectStandardError = True,
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        }
   }
```

Comment: Why are you starting an executable from inside a web application at all? That's a **very** serious performance and security problem. It means that multiple processes could start simply because of a page refresh, and that anyone who could hack the site would be able to run any executable he wanted

Comment: If you want to run a long-running job from a web site, use something like Hangfire

Comment: Thanks for the info but it seems that Hangfire is overkill for my situation. This is an internal web app, so we are not worried about hacking. The console app takes around 20-30 to complete and they only run this around 1 time per week. I will investigate that as another option down the road.

Comment: that is 20-30 sec.

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging it seems to be a permissions issue. I did not think this was an issue before because the asp.net is using windows auth with impersonation and the userid has admin rights on the machine. But I guess it has something to do with the application pool identity. If I change it to a user account with higher permissions, then the above code works. I did read somewhere else that if you add .Domain, .User, .Password attributes to the above code it still doesn't work unless the app pool identity is the same user. So I guess I am stuck with just forgetting about redirecting the output and just use UseShellExecute = True instead.